# Bypass printer driver with powershell

Tags: powershell, printing, driver

with an PowerShell script, we create a file that contains text and PCL commands to produce a nicely formatted page, I need to print this file on an local attached printer. 
Unfortunately the PowerShell cmdlet `Out-Printer` formats the output and destroys the PCL commands, so `Out-Printer` is unusable for this job.

Sending the file to a LPR printer works as expected,

```
$socket = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($global:remoteHost, $global:port)
$stream = $socket.GetStream() 
$writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream,[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252))
$writer.Write($str2write)
$writer.Flush() 
$writer.Close()
$stream.Close()
```

Unfortunately this approach works only with TCP printers but not with locally attached printers.

So what I need is PowerShell code to place this file directly into the Windows printer queue, bypassing the Windows printer driver.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [rawprn.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-DK/troubleshoot/windows/win32/win32-raw-data-to-printer) from Microsoft (you can download the executable). In order to print a ZPL file on a Zebra label printer I use:

```
Start-Process "C:\rawprint\RawPrint.exe" -NoNewWindow -Wait -ArgumentList "`"Zebra GK420d raw`" `"file.zpl`""
```

Answer (score -1):

To answer my own question, I found this German post:

https://newyear2006.wordpress.com/2016/10/17/direkte-kommunikation-mit-druckern-unter-windows-von-powershell-aus/

this solved my issue, works perfect.

Comment: While the linked page may answer the question, it is [better to include the essential parts _here_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248777) and provide the link only for reference / additional information. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page disappears or changes substantially. Additionally, there's a language barrier in this case, given that the linked post is in German.